# Find unencrypted AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services

The company I work for would like to ensure the AWS services we use are as encrypted as possible.

That means at-rest S3 encryption, SSL encrypted connections between services, encrypted RDS, etc.

But those are just the services we know of.

Is there any way to easily scan our AWS accounts for services and connections between services that can be encrypted, but aren't? Something like a security audit?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/). It is exactly what it does. It watches your AWS account and allows you to define rules to check for configuration settings in AWS. It comes with a list of predefined rules that simplify getting started.

Comment: Thanks, looking at the standard rules included it seems to cover some of the services. But it does not include checking of, for instance, client-side encryption of S3 storage for SES or checks on many of the connections.

Comment: No sadly there is not yet one service that covers everything.